# Import Opencart orders left behind in old database

Tags: php, sql, database, opencart

I'll try explain myself simply to get across the jist of what's happened.

I have an OpenCart store. I just transferred hosts, the new site went live but some people were still seeing the old cached copy, so some orders carried on going to the old server/database. Order `#0003, #0004, #0005`.

Then the propagation finished and people continued ordering, now the new database didn't have order, `#0003, #0004, #0005` already like it should have done so it assigned these very new orders those id numbers. Now the original `3,4,5` is left behind on the old database and needs importing, but if I import them it'll conflict with the **NEW** `3,4,5` order id's.

Is there a way I can import orders to a database which has already assigned the same order-id numbers to other people/accounts?

Comment: You will have to change the order numbers

Comment: Do you know what associated tables in the database need to be copied over? And is it literally only the ID I need the change, anything else?

Comment: I have not used opencart for ages but I think NO :)